# OpenCv: change position of putText()

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I made a deep learning program that uses the webcam to recognize a persons emotion, race and gender. The text shows a persons characteristics is inside of each other. How can I move them underneath each other?

[image: Demo of the program]

*The code*

```
while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    result = DeepFace.analyze(frame,  actions=['emotion', "race", "gender"], enforce_detection=False)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (50, 50, 50), 2)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['dominant_emotion'],
               (50, 50),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['gender'],
               (40, 50),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['dominant_race'],
               (30, 50),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)
               

    cv2.imshow('Facial rec.', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: you have to manually change `y` (second value) in `(50, 50)`, `(40, 50)`, `(30, 50)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `y` - second value in `(50,50), (40,50), (30,50)`  - ie. `(50,50), (50,80), (50,110)`

---

Minimal working code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    result = {'dominant_emotion': 'hello', "gender": 'world', "dominant_race": 'of python'}

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['dominant_emotion'],
               (50, 50),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['gender'],
               (50, 80),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)

    cv2.putText(frame,
               result['dominant_race'],
               (50, 110),
               font, 1,
               (220, 220, 220),
               2,
               cv2.LINE_4)

    cv2.imshow('Facial rec.', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

`cv2` has also `getTextSize()` to calculate text height and use it to set position for next line.

```
(width, height), baseline = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_scale, font_thickness)
```

---

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    result = {'dominant_emotion': 'hello', "gender": 'world', "dominant_race": 'of python'}

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
    font_scale = 1
    font_thickness = 2
    
    x = 50
    y = 50
    
    for text in result.values():
        cv2.putText(frame,
                   text,
                   (x, y),
                   font, font_scale,
                   (220, 220, 220),
                   font_thickness,
                   cv2.LINE_4)
        
        (width, height), baseline = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_scale, font_thickness)
        y += (height + 10)  # +10 margin

    cv2.imshow('Facial rec.', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot that x is the first value and y is the second value. Explains why I used to fail math classes

Comment: I was wondering if CV has function to measure font height to change `y` automatically - and I found `getTextSize` - I added example with `getTextSize`

Comment: BTW: graphics modules and GUIs use `x,y` but math modules (like `numpy`, `pandas`) and GEO locations use `y,x` - and sometimes it makes problems :)